# Which scripture is this shloka from? (vijñātāramare kena vijāniyāt)

Tags: scripture, mantras, shloka, reference-request

I am trying to identify which scripture this sloka is from.   I came across this sloka in a book:

> vijñātāramare kena vijāniyāt
> विज्ञातारमरे केन विजानियात

When researching online I found this [website](https://www.hindisamay.com/content/11825/1/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A6-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A6-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%82-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A6.cspx) which contains the sloka, but it does not tell from which scripture it is.
Does anyone else know?

Comment: Brihadharayaka upanishad 4.5.15
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc122154.html

Comment: @Athrey - you should add that as an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This famous verse is from
**Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad,4.5.15**

---

> यत्र हि द्वैतमिव भवति तदितर इतरं पश्यति, तदितर इतरंजिघ्रति, तदितर इतरं
> रसयते, तदितर इतरमभिवदति, तदितर इतरं शृणोति, तदितर इतरं मनुते, तदितर
> इतरं स्पृशति, तदितर इतरं विजानाति; यत्र त्वस्य सर्वमात्मैवाभूत्,
> तत्केन कं पश्येत्, तत्केन कं जिघ्रेत्, तत्केन कं रसयेत्, तत्केन
> कमभिवदेत्, तत्केन कं शृणुयात्, तत्केन कं मन्वीत तत्केन कं स्पृशेत्,
> तत्केन कं विजानीयात्? येनेदं सर्वं विजानाति तं केन विजानीयात्? स एष
> नेति नेत्यात्मा, अगृह्यो न हि गृह्यते, अशीर्यो न हि शीर्यते, असङ्गो न
> हि सज्यते, असितो न व्यथते, न रिष्यति; **विज्ञातारमरे केन विजानीयात्**,
> इत्युक्तानुशासनासि मैत्रेयि, एतावदरे खल्वमृतत्वमिति होक्त्वा
> याज्ञवल्क्यो विजहार ॥
>
> **~ Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad,4.5.15**
>
> Because when there is duality, as it were, then one sees something,
> one smells something, one tastes something, one speaks something, one
> hears something, one thinks something, one touches something, one
> knows something. But when to the knower of Brahman everything has
> become the Self, then what should one see and through what, what
> should one smell and through what, what should one taste and through
> what, what should one speak and through what, what should one hear and
> through what, what should one think and through what, what should one
> touch and through what, what should one know and through what? Through
> what should one know that owing to which all this is known? This self
> is That which has been described as ‘Not this, not this.’ It is
> imperceptible, for It is never perceived; undecaying, for It never
> decays; unattached, for It is never attached; unfettered—it never
> feels pain, and never suffers injury. **Through what, O Maitreyī,
> should one know the Knower?** So you have got the instruction,
> Maitreyī. This much indeed is (the means of) immortality, my dear.
> Saying this Yājña-valkya left.